# Can't move into Lakeview or Windstad?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I purchased the plot for Windstad Manor first, I completely finished the house with all available furnishings and decorations inside and out, but when I went to Breezehome to have my husband and daughter move in they wouldn't. The dialogue came up but they never left the house. I waited a whole day then tried again but the same happened.
I figured maybe it's a bug with that area and didn't really like the land anyways so I retried with Lakeview. I just finished the perfect house with my farm set up and beds and dressers for children and all that good stuff but the same thing happened. I checked and now there's options to go to Windstad and Lakeview but my family won't budge. After reading a few other pages I saw something about the stats so I checked and it says I only have one home. How do I get it to register my other two homes without having to redo everything?